# I want to toggle between event binds in tkinter python 3.1

Tags: python, tkinter

I trying to toggle between events using tkinter python 3.1

#https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/tkinter.html
    #python 3.1

```
from tkinter import *

def hello(event):
    print("hello -Single Click, Button-l")

def goodbye(event):                           
    print("goodbye -Single Click, Button-1") 

#if count == 1:
#NameError: name 'count' is not defined
# have to add count = 1
count = 1 # now it sets count to 1 every loop.
widget = Button(None, text='Mouse Clicks')
widget.pack()

#toggle with each click first time "hello" second time "goodbye"
if count == 1:
    widget.bind('<Button-1>', hello)
    count == 0
else:
    widget.bind('<Button-1>', goodby)
    count == 1
widget.mainloop()
```

How do I prevent count from being set to 1 every time through the loop so I can toggle between events?

Comment: What loop? Other than `mainloop` you don't have a loop. All of the code before `widget.mainloop()` executes exactly once.

Comment: No it doesn't.  It loops through the entire program continuously setting count = 1

Comment: You are incorrect. A simple print statement will show you the code executes exactly once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to alter the binding *inside* of your callback functions. As it is, `count` is always 1 when the `if` statement is evaluated (and this statement is only evaluated once), so `hello` will *always* be the callback.

To do this, you can do the following.

```
widget = Button(None, text='Mouse Clicks')

def hello(event):
    print("hello -Single Click, Button-l")
    widget.bind('<Button-1>', goodbye)

def goodbye(event):
    print("goodbye -Single Click, Button-1") 
    widget.bind('<Button-1>', hello)

# Initial bind
widget.bind('<Button-1>', hello)
```

Comment: This is the program I was actually trying to do this with.  Thanks to Suever it works now.